# What does "in such cases" in the extract refer to?

Tags: word-usage, sentence-construction

> It is frequently observed that a filler metal will
> continue to spread beyond an initially wetted
> surface area over an extended period of time
> (>10 s), which would not be expected from classical
> fluid-flow theory. **Clearly, classical expressions
> for fluid flow, exemplified by Eq 1.4, do not
> strictly apply in such cases.** Indeed, this type of
> flow can usually be associated with solid-liquid
> interfacial reactions, which are neglected in the
> model described in Milner’s paper [1958].

Is “such cases” referred to Eq 1.4?

Can this sentence be rewritten as “to exemplified Eq 1.4, classical expressions for fluid flow do not strictly apply to Eq 1.4”?

Comment: We do not allow images of text on this site because they cannot be searched for. Please use the "Edit" button, type only the portion of the text you're asking about, and remove the image.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Notice I didn't close the question, just asked the OP to replace the image with text. Someone reading the site on a text-only browser would have no way of reading the original text.

Comment: I would give a second upvote just for copying the text out, but  we only have one vote per post. 

Answer (score 1):

> It is frequently observed that a filler metal will continue to spread beyond an initially wetted surface area over an extended period of time (>10 s), which would not be expected from classical fluid-flow theory. Clearly, classical expressions for fluid flow, exemplified by Eq 1.4, do not strictly apply in such cases. Indeed, this type of flow can usually be associated with solid-liquid interfacial reactions, which are neglected in the model described in Milner’s paper [1958].

This passage says *such cases*, of continued filler metal spread, are not expected from/ do not conform to the classical fluid-flow theory.  This theory neglected such solid-liquid interfacial reactions in its model.

*such cases* refers to cases not conforming to the classical fluid-flow theory.

No, your suggested rewritten sentence does not mean the same as

> Clearly, classical expressions for fluid flow, exemplified by Eq 1.4, do not strictly apply in such cases.

In fact, classical expressions for fluid flow **is** exemplified/illustrated by Eq 1.4.

> exemplify
> verb [ T ] UK  /ɪɡˈzem.plɪ.faɪ/ US  /ɪɡˈzem.plə.faɪ/
> C2

> to be or give a typical example of something:

> This painting perfectly exemplifies the naturalistic style which was so popular at the time.

[Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/exemplify)

Answer (score 0):

The opening sentence says that the phenomenon where 'a filler metal ... (>10s)' i contradicts classical fluid flow theory. And Eq.14 *is* an expression of classical fluid flow theory. So the 'such cases' is those where 'a filler ... (>10s)'.

Comment: in such cases means: in cases such as this.